# Progress Bar value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been trying to figure out how to make the progress bar display correctly for a while, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an integer value (<% goal.ppercent %>) that I want to set as the value of the progress of the bar.  When I try to change any of the "aria-value" it doesn't change the progress bar, but when I change the style=" width: " value it changes the bar.  Can somebody explain to me how to do the bootstrap progress bar correctly?

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow= 
    <% goal.ppercent %> aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
    <%= number_to_percentage(goal.ppercent, precision: 0) %> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the width of the inner `.progress-bar` in order to change the percentage.

ARIA just stands for Accessible Rich Internet Applications. It's just a set of attributes that make web content more accessible to people with disabilities. In fact, you don't have to have ARIA attributes in order for the process bar to work.

Since you have the percentage, just go ahead and update `.process-bar`'s width as well.

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" 
      role="progressbar" 
      aria-valuenow=<% goal.ppercent %> aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
      style="width: <% goal.ppercent %>%;">
        <%= number_to_percentage(goal.ppercent, precision: 0) %> 
    </div>
</div>
```